# Failed to load plugin (gazebo-11)

Tags: ros, gazebo, gazebo-11, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello, I am using ROS2 Foxy (built from source) and gazebo11 (installed by command `sudo apt install ros-foxy-gazebo-ros-pkgs`) on Ubuntu 20.04.1. When I  try to follow the test from installing tutorial (http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros2_installing&cat=connect_ros) I get an error:

[`Err] [Plugin.hh:178] Failed to load plugin libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so: libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

on the step:

`gazebo --verbose /opt/ros/eloquent/share/gazebo_plugins/worlds/gazebo_ros_diff_drive_demo.world`

I already cheeked GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH, it point directly to the folder where the .so file is located.

Thanks for helping.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25906/failed-to-load-plugin-(gazebo-11)/) by [faade](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/34000/faade/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi @faade,

Did you source the ROS 2 workspace in the terminal that you are running Gazebo?

```
source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash
```

Regards

---

Originally posted by [ahcorde](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26408/ahcorde/) with karma: 281 on 2020-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1